# How to add border for the buttons in android

Tags: android, button, border

Hi I am using buttons in my list view. I would like to add border to my button. How can i do that. 
My XML code for creating button look like this.

android:text="Search"
>

Please suggest me some solution or provide me some source code for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create the background new (9patch drawable) and then set it to the background.
How to do this is explained here:
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1239